# Django - template tag "with" in javascript

Tags: python, django

How can i use the django `with` template tag in external JavaScript file?
I tried to use it like this:

```
<script>
    //some code
    //
    {% with user|get_song_rating:opts.id as rated %}
        {% if rated %}
           $off.unbind('click').unbind('mousemove').unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
           $off.css('cursor', 'default'); $on.css('cursor', 'default');
           $this.attr('title', 'Your rating: ' + rated.points.toFixed(1));
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</script>
```

But it gives error in console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token with`. I think the issue is `with` is the keyword for JavaScript also, so what is the solution?

Comment: That's not it, these are two different layers - Django doesn't care about javascript when rendering your html. Seems that you're using {% with %} incorrectly.

Comment: This is how I am using a `with` tag do you see any issue in syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your file to contain Django template tags then it must be processed by the Django template engine. Create a new view that sends the proper `Content-type` header for JavaScript source and then processes and outputs the template that contains JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! it just worked. Can you please tell me how can I pass `opts.id` which is a JavaScript variable in to the template filter? It raise exception now `failed lookup for key opts`

Comment: You can't. You will need to use AJAX to pass the variable to a view and then return the results as JSON.